# Strange course of actions with migrated and deleted question

Tags: support, bug, down-votes, migration, deleted-questions

Can someone please explain the course of actions with this question for me:

> - [Stack Overflow - Developer Story Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333895/stack-overflow-developer-story-tab)

It's the second time I see that now within a week.

1. The question received a (single) close and down vote from my side as being applicable only for a specific site (Stack Overflow in this case)
2. The question was migrated to Meta Stack Overflow
3. The question was deleted (voluntarily by author)
4. Now it's shown as [on hold] here on Meta Stack Exchange
5. If I click the link to see it again, I am redirected to Meta Stack Overflow and see a 404
6. The question received additional downvotes after it was deleted (or not?)

My question is about the last point: How can that be?

Is that a bug, or do I miss something in the course of actions were taken?

Could that be some caching issue? (I know well, it's always caching ;-) )
For my best knwoledge I actively reloaded any relevant pages in my browser.

Comment: The fact that you're still redirected to MSO is probably due to caching on your end. For me, it links to a question here that was closed as off-topic with a generic reason.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333897/strange-course-of-actions-with-migrated-and-deleted-question?noredirect=1#comment1090356_333898

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a migrated question is closed (as anything other than duplicate) or deleted on the destination site, the migration gets rejected. That returns the question back to its origin site, by unlocking it there and changing it to simply "closed as off-topic" (which is the reason that migration lives under - emphasizing that the question *should be* off-topic here in order to be eligible for migration).

Since the question is no longer locked, it's just another closed question on the site eligible to be downvoted.

If you're still getting redirected after the migration was rejected, that's likely your browser caching the redirect response from before and not reloading the whole page (I've experienced this before when trying to undo a redirect on a personal project, but it usually wears off quickly). It's not something our system does and I cannot reproduce such an action.

Comment: But reloading the page in my browser,still doesn't show it at MSE?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure what you mean. Are you expecting the MSO question to redirect back to MSE after the rejection? That's not something we do.

Comment: No, I don't expect any redirection, but seeing the original MSE question after clicking the link at the MSE home page (at least after reloading it in my browser), but I cannot see it, I am still redirected to MSO. Why is that?

Comment: I believe my last paragraph covers exactly that.

Comment: OK, deleting the browsers cached data from the settings (instead of just reloading)  did the trick (you should mention this in your answer as well). Thank you.