# Migration bug? Re-migrating a question to the same site didn't create a new question on the destination site

Tags: support, moderator-tools, migration, migration-rejection

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/333895/revisions) was migrated from here to Meta Stack Overflow. The author then voluntarily deleted it there, which marked the migration as "rejected" and reversed all effects of the migration (except the part where it was closed as "off-topic").

The question was then re-migrated to Meta Stack Overflow by a different moderator, but that process didn't create a new question there; it instead re-linked it with the (deleted) original migration. The ending effect is that users who click on the migrated question here are redirected to a voluntarily deleted question on the destination site.

Why doesn't re-migrating a question after it was rejected originally create a new question on the destination site? Why did it re-associate it with the original migration that was rejected?

Screenshot of the revision history:

> [image: Same question migrated]

The blue line in the revision history above represents the point in that post's history when the proposed duplicate question was asked; my question is about the items in the history that took place *after* (above) that blue line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange course of actions with migrated and deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333897/strange-course-of-actions-with-migrated-and-deleted-question)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not a duplicate. Your question was asked before the re-migration; mine was asked afterwards. This is a completely new bug. I've cleared my browser cache multiple times before asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explicitly intentional: there's a check on the destination site - if a question exists with the same source as the new migration, it just returns a link.

It sounds like you're recommending that this be changed to ignore either questions which have been rejected (probably a bad idea, at least in cases where the question was closed as off-topic) or questions which have been deleted (possibly a good one).

I'm changing this to a feature-request to reflect this. Please edit your request as need-be.

Comment: Also, the purpose of this question was to ask *why* this was the case (hence the [tag:support] tag in the initial revision); the tag was later incorrectly removed. You wouldn't mind if I instead edit the tag back into [tag:support]?

Comment: I have asked the same question on `meta.stackoverflow` and question does not get a single response. So I thought that meta.StackExchange will be the right place to ask but that was my bad. So I deleted the question (don't want to create the duplicate question again) which is now showing as migrated. (mod may delete the question if required as it was not the right to place for question)what can be an appropriate way to get the answer to the question? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389686/developer-story-tab-redirect-to-tag

Comment: Alternatively, can't the redirect mode be changed (from what I assume is "moved permanently" to "See Other") to solve the issue?