# Warn users when voting to close for a specific reason if the question was previously closed for that reason and reopened

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

I've noticed each of the following scenarios happening quite a bit:

1. A question is incorrectly identified as meeting a specific close reason and is closed.
2. The author or other users comment as to why the question is already a good fit for the site as is (i.e., why the closure was incorrect or why the answers in the duplicate target don't address the question). They may also edit the explanation into the question. Alternatively, the question is brought up on meta where users come to a consensus that the question is a good fit or not a duplicate. The question is reopened.
3. As the question is reopened, commentary about it being incorrectly closed is now obsolete. It is edited out of the question or the comments are deleted as no longer needed.
4. Other users who haven't seen the question or its history previously, or the meta discussion on the question if it exists, also incorrectly identify the question as meeting that specific close reason. The question ends up incorrectly closed again.
5. The author is then forced to go through the same steps again, but they and the other users who previously participated in the reopening are extremely limited in what they can do. They cannot vote to reopen again due to the system provision that prevents close/reopen wars. They cannot raise a new meta discussion since one already exists so a new one would be a duplicate (if the site meta regards it that way; to be fair, some don't). They can only re-edit the same commentary and submit it as an edit for reopening, and hope that a completely different set of users come by and vote to reopen.

A similar set of scenarios involves questions that do correctly deserve to be closed, are then edited to be a good fit or not a duplicate, and are then incorrectly voted for the same reason again.

Some specific examples of the above:

- A question is asked here on this meta about the code formatting filter. Users come by and vote to close the question as "only applicable to one specific site", incorrectly believing that the filter is only enabled on Stack Overflow (which can be amplified by the user mentioning Stack Overflow in their question). Someone with more knowledge comes by and comments that the question should be reopened because the code filter is enabled on more than one site and the close reason guidance says that the reason shouldn't be applied on questions that can be applied to multiple sites even though they focus on one. The question is reopened, and the comment is deleted as no longer needed. Someone else who wasn't aware of the prior history of the question votes to close it for the same prior reason again.
- A user asks a question that already exists on the site and has some answers. Users close the question as a duplicate of the previous one. The author attempts the answers in the target, but none of them solve the problem. They then edit in a link to the target and an explanation as to why the answers didn't solve the problem, being sure to put it front and center, at the beginning of the question and emphasized. The question is reopened. The author keeps the information, but moves it to the bottom of the question and removes the emphasis as it doesn't need to be front and center for reviewers anymore (but is still necessary for the question to not be a duplicate). Someone who doesn't read the note at the bottom votes to close it as a duplicate of the same question again.
- A fairly new beta site is working to define its scope and gets a question which is controversial as to whether it's in scope for the site or not. The question gets a Leave Open review in the review queue, but it's controversial with as many or more reviewers voting to close, and gets its final close vote outside of review. The author or someone else starts a discussion about it or the topic it's asking about, and the discussion concludes with a consensus that the question is within the site's scope, and as such it's reopened. Someone who didn't participate in the prior discussion comes across the question and votes to close it again, not knowing of the prior consensus.

In any case, despite the prior successful attempt to have the question reopened, some of which may involve getting consensus from the site meta, if the question is closed for the same reason again, not much can be done to reverse it. This mostly occurs because users can't/don't see the prior history of the question getting closed for the reason previously and reopened. If users could see that, they'd be more likely to check for why the question was previously reopened, and once they see those reasons, they could see if those invalidate the reasons they were voting to close.

The best solution to fix the problem, in my opinion, is to warn users who are voting to close a question for a specific reason if the question was previously closed for that reason and was reopened. This warning should be shown in the close dialog underneath the applicable reason option. Users should still be able to vote to close for that reason anyway, because it may be warranted in certain circumstances (such as in the second case above, if someone posts a new answer to the target that does address the newer question, or in the third case above, if consensus later changes to make the question not in scope). This would also resolve [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333907/migration-bug-re-migrating-a-question-to-the-same-site-didnt-create-a-new-ques) where moderators aren't shown if a question was migrated to a site previously and rejected, as re-migrating to the same site will re-associate the question with the past migration attempt rather than creating a new question on the destination.

Comment: You have three examples where someone voted to close the question again - did the question actually get closed again, though? One of the reasons that closing requires several participants is to ensure that it's actually the correct outcome... so, in the second example, if the voter didn't see the comment at the bottom one would hope the reviewers would.

Comment: @Catija The third example is my very first question on Interpersonal Skills. The question was reopened after a meta discussion but was then voted to close again - by a moderator thereby making the vote binding. I don't have exact links for the first two examples, but I do remember myself intervening by editing in a bolded explanation at the top to ward off incorrect close votes; I believe the questions would have almost certainly been re-closed had I gone AFK at the time.

Answer (score 2):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

For posts on main sites with discussion on the meta site, I don't see a problem with keeping around a single comment on the post on the main site that points to the meta post.

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The above manual process can be baked into the UI by adding a "Linked Meta Posts" to the sidebar of question pages on main sites which lists meta posts that contain a link to that main post, or meta posts linked to in the main post.

Or show such a list as part of the closure process. If there's a problem of meta discussion unrelated to closure or on/off-topicality, only show meta posts if the meta post contains certain keywords like "close" or tags related to closure or on/off-topicality.

This could be taken a step further by adding a "Ask Meta Question" button to the review queue UI. It could fill in the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag, and fill in a link to the review item and post in the question body.

I'm not 100% convinced it's a good idea (more like 60%), but I think it's worth discussing and giving thought.

[I made this suggestion recently as an answer](/a/386962/997587) to a different discussion: [Reviewers should be able to communicate with each other about a review task](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386954/997587).

Comment: Not every question is discussed on the site's meta, especially on smaller sites. On many sites, close voting and close review is where decisions are made on the site, with few active users participating in meta, so this wouldn't be a solution for those sites.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog yep. agreed. But if an incorrect closure happens, I'd hope something happes so that the close-voters learn why it's wrong. That can happen on meta, in the comments, or in chat. As you mentioned, there are problems with doing it in comments, and doing it on meta can be good for teaching more users if the problem isn't something that's happened much before. If there's pre-existing meta discussion, a link to that can be added to the comments of the main-site post.

Answer (score 1):

A question can only be closed twice if two different sets of people think it should be closed ([since you cannot vote to close twice on a question unless your previous vote expired](/a/10583)), or a moderator or gold-badge holder is involved.

1. Two groups of users: the evident consensus is that the question does not meet the requirements to stay open, despite some dissent. Telling the second group that they should reconsider their vote in this case is pointless - they are making their decision based on the question they see now, and do not need to consider what other people think of it. That is why it takes five votes to close (or three on some sites).
2. A gold badge or moderator made the first closure: a matching round of closure and reopen votes is the community in disagreement. If the second closure is successful, it appears the moderator judgement was at worst met with some dissent and some support, and therefore not sufficiently incorrect to be disputed beyond the closure/reopen system.
3. A gold badge or moderator made the second closure: these users know enough to check the history if they think it necessary, and otherwise are considered expert enough to make a valid decision on their own to resolve the community disagreement.
4. A gold badge or moderator made both closures: either the question really is that bad and the community is not recognising the issue, or somebody is abusing their privileges. This needs to go to meta regardless, a reminder will not be helpful on the question now.

There is just no case where such a notice is helpful to anybody. At best it is one more click to hide, and more likely is systemically influencing people not to make their own votes - which defeats the purpose of making them individual votes and requiring a consensus or a very exclusive privilege to overcome.

Comment: In the first of my examples, it's not simply opinion or unofficial community consensus that the question shouldn't be closed, but explicitly in the site rules (check the close dialog; it specifically states that questions that have to do with multiple sites shouldn't be closed with the "relates to one specific site" reason even if they focus on one site). You're assuming that in all cases it would be the former, but it can also be the latter. In this case, merely pointing out a second site where one would have the same issue is enough to invalidate the close reason.

Comment: Also, if it were true that question closure/reopening shouldn't take into account others' opinions, then SE would take steps to obscure the number of pending close/reopen votes or the current reviews on an active close/reopen review task, but they don't do so.

Comment: Knowing the number of people who have voted to close is irrelevant to whether the next person should vote to close, but that's not the only reason that information about closure exists, so that is a nonsense thing to mention. You're complaining about some very specific issues that are already soluble without needing this notification, and in fact, such a notification would do nothing to support those solutions. So, this is still a pointless "feature".